# Staying 'logged in' even when app destroyed

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-lifecycle

Hi I have an App which has a strict requirement of appearing "logged in" even following the app being destroyed. If the App was destroyed then later re-loaded (if previously logged in)  login screen should be bypassed > directly to the page the user was previously viewing. (I already handle all session related variables)

I've tried using `Shared Preferences` but if I destroy the App manually it would go back to the login screen, I can't have this happen.

I tried storing preferences manually in the DB (which is probably what `Shared Preferences` does anyway?) but it still loads the Login Activity of course because this is my first loaded activity. So this problem is more a case of keeping a preference on which Activity the user is on at all time then loading directly to this `onResume()`.

My question: Has anyone dealt with this sort of scenario before? How should I approach pre-loading the Activity. I was thinking that when I load my preferences within the Login screen  I check the previous Activity preference and simply load into that (assuming user is  logged in).

Is there a better way to approach this? Is there a more native way of loading dynamically to appropriate Activity start?

Any help is really appreciated

**Edit**: Ok just after posting this I realised all I really had to do was add a check in OnResume whether the appropriate session variable was set. then load into the Activity, actually just as Akbari says below. I've rolled my Preferences class back to using the standard Android `SharePreferences` and its working perfectly now. happy about that :)

Simply doing something like this:

```
    // load preferences
    preferences.readPreferences();      

    // if preferences exist load straight to RecordActivity
    if (application.currentSessionId!=null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecordActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);           
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save login status in preferences and check it in onCreate() method of your Login activity

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);SharedPreferences prefs;
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("your_pref", MODE_PRIVATE);

    boolean login_status = prefs.getBoolean("login_status", false);
    if (login_status) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "UserInfo>>User already logged in");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Here, it will check login status and redirect user to next activity if already logged in

Comment: actually just after I posted that question I realised its far more simple than I thought. I'd essentially implemented exactly as you say here. Cheers :)

Comment: fantastic, I've just changed my preferences Class back to using `SharePreferences` instead of a manual database save and its still working perfectly. Very happy with that outcome